# Can't enable Enhanced Mode for Ubuntu 19.04 in Hyper-V on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, hyper-v

I'm on Windows 10 Pro version 2004 build 19041.84.

Trying to run Ubuntu 19.04 with GUI in Hyper-V. Runs like a potato which apparently requires putting the VM into Enhanced Mode to get it run somewhat usable.

Numerous blogs said just use "Quick Create" and select Ubuntu 19.04. After it downloads, installs and restarts, reconnect to it, it should automatically start in Enhanced Mode with a menu asking about resolution.

None of that happens.

Enhanced Mode is enabled throughout Hyper-V Settings.

I've found older blogs with a list of commands to run in Powershell and in the VM after it is installed, but from what I gather that is no longer necessary in new version of Hyper-V and Windows 10 with "Quick Create"

How do I get this working properly?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get this working properly?

You should switch to a Hyper-V optimized Linux kernel

Switching to the Hyper-V optimized kernel by running `sudo apt install linux-azure` and then removing the old kernel with `sudo apt autoremove --purge` and then perform a shutdown of the VM.

Source: [Hyper-V enhance mode 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184538/hyper-v-enhance-mode-19-04)