# Enhanced Mode laggy on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

I finally was able to get Enhanced Mode working with [some help](https://superuser.com/questions/1526800/cant-enable-enhanced-mode-for-ubuntu-19-04-in-hyper-v-on-windows-10-pro) on Windows 10 Pro in Hyper-V.

While it drastically improved the performance, I feel like it is still sluggish. I've read some people saying they are getting something like +60FPS while I feel like I am getting maybe 20-30 FPS.

I guess I've been spoiled by Parallels on macOS where running a Windows box feels like running it natively on the hardware.

The steps I followed were:

1. In Hyper-V select "Quick Create"
2. Select "Ubunutu 19.04"
3. Select "Create Virtual Machine"
4. After it is created I edit by giving it 8GB RAM minimum and 6 cores
5. Start up the new VM
6. Install Ubuntu
7. Restart
8. Launch Terminal
9. `sudo apt install linux-azure`
10. `sudo apt autoremove --purge`
11. Turn off the VM
12. Restart it
13. Enhanced Mode is now working

Again, a significant improvement, but still sluggish.

What else can be done to improve the performance or achieve what some people are claiming to get (>60FPS)?

Running on a Razer Blade Advanced early-2019 (i7-8750H, RTX 2080, 64GB RAM, 4TB Sabrent Rocket NVMe M.2 SSD).

I did try switching between my Windows Power Plans (Best Performance, Balanced, Power Savings)... there was no discernible difference.

I did try `linux-vm-tools`. There was no noticeable difference in performance than what is described in the steps above.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with version 20.04. After a lot of poking and prodding, I found a solution that worked for me. The quick create option set the number of virtual processors (under settings/processor) to 6 on my machine. I changed it to 1 and all is well. Seems counterintuitive but it did the trick.

Comment: Why are you submitting the same answer to multiple questions.  Please don’t do that.  If a single answer, answers multiple questions, then flag those questions as a duplicate

Comment: Seems counterintuitive because it's probably the wrong answer.