# How to change user for Hyper-V Enhanced Session?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-11

When I originally installed Windows 11 **(GUEST OS)** in Hyper-V I logged in with one user, but now I want to change to a different user. Every time I switch users it switches back to a Basic Session. When I enable Enhanced Session is goes back to the original user.

I tried disabling and reenabling [Enhanced Session support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/learn-more/use-local-resources-on-hyper-v-virtual-machine-with-vmconnect#turn-on-enhanced-session-mode-on-a-hyper-v-host), but that didn't seem to help either. I'm guessing I'm either missing something really simple or it just isn't supported.

I'm running Hyper-V Manager v 10.0.22000.1 on Windows 11 Pro v 21H2 **(HOST OS)**.

Is there any way to change the user used with the Hyper-V Enhanced Session?

*NOTE:* I've upgraded the Guest OS to Windows 11 since having two different versions of Windows was causing some confusion. It is now Windows 11 all the way down. Still no Linux. Hope that helps.

Comment: What OS is installed on the VM? If it's Linux [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1526800/cant-enable-enhanced-mode-for-ubuntu-19-04-in-hyper-v-on-windows-10-pro/1526897#1526897) is the reason you can't enable it.  You mentioned Windows 10 in the first sentence, and Windows 11 in the last sentence, only one of those could be true.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 10 is the guest, Windows 11 is the host. Both are true. I clarified the question by explicitly indicating which is Guest and which is Host. I thought it was clear by saying I was installing Windows 10 **in** Hyper-V on Windows 11. There is no Linux involved.

Comment: I hope you will reverse your vote to close once you have a chance to re-read the question and understand it correctly. I can upgrade the guest OS to Windows 11 if that simplifies things.

Comment: @JimMcKeeth did you ever figure this out? I'm running into this limitation.

Comment: @Chris Sort of. The issue was that the user I added had a PIN to log-in instead of a password. When I changed it to a regular password it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear the issue was that the new user account I added was using a PIN to log in, and Hyper-V Enhanced Sessions only work if you log in with a regular password.