# What is the purpose of "enhanced connection" in Windows-10 Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hypervisor, hyper-v-manager

I am learning about virtual machines (VMs); based on early google hits, I created a virtual machine with a program called "Hyper-V Manger" that was already installed on my Windows 10 laptop. I chose Ubuntu 18.04 LTS as the guest OS. Installation appeared to be uneventful and successful.

After setup, I see the familiar Ubuntu login screen, but it's overlayed by a *Windows* window titled "Connect to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS":

[image]

Since *Connect* seems the only useful button, I click it and I'm taken to this "xrdp just connecting screen":

[image]

If I log in, I remain at an empty blue desktop with no icons, and nothing to interact with:

[image]

After being stumped by what to do here yesterday, today, I noticed that In the VM's toolbar, there is a button that lets you toggle between "Enhanced session" and "Basic session" -- and when I toggle it to "Basic session" I arrive back at the "normal" Ubuntu interface that I'd have expected on a "PC" running Ubuntu, i.e. the login screen, GNOME Shell desktop, etc.:

[image]

---

**Question:**

What is the purpose of the "Enhanced connection" that just takes you to a blank desktop with nothing to interact with?

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/questions/1526800/cant-enable-enhanced-mode-for-ubuntu-19-04-in-hyper-v-on-windows-10-pro/1526897#1526897) is an answer I provided on this subject 2 years ago.  Running just `Set-VM -VMName <your_vm_name>  -EnhancedSessionTransportType HvSocket` likely won't be enough given you are running Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the enhanced session mode, you can resize the screen of the VM and
copy and paste text from a host to guest and vice versa.

Unfortunately, this mode only works for host and guest both being on
a reasonably recent Windows version.
When the guest is Linux, it must be configured for this mode.

See the article
[Detailed Walkthrough: Install Ubuntu 20.04 on Hyper-V with Enhanced Session](https://www.nakivo.com/blog/install-ubuntu-20-04-on-hyper-v-with-enhanced-session/)
for a very detailed description with many screenshots.
There is also supplied a shell script to configure the VM.